# Clipping aerial photograph with LiDAR tiffs for sediment volume calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, lidar, volume

I currently have an aerial photograph of a barrier beach, and corresponding LiDAR data for the 2005 photo, 2007 photo, and 2013 photo.

I want to calculate the volume of sediment on the beach for each year above sea level. There are various guides but I am still confused how to do this for just the area of beach I have, and not the whole area of LiDAR. The LiDAR files are tiff.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

One approach: you can clip a raster with a tool from your toolboxes, Data Management -> Raster -> Raster Processing. There are various routes with for getting volume, but if you have raster data you can use the [Surface Volume tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000027000000).

You should also understand the error associated with your LiDAR derived raster and the estimates of volume and how that impacts your results.